# How to use string frequencies list in Trie data structure?

Tags: java, data-structures, trie

I am working on some performance test on various data structures. In my list I have HashMap and Trie data structure. I am done with HashMap but not sure how to use Trie for below problem -

I have a text file which contains 2 million english words with their frequencies in this format -

```
hello 100
world 5000
good 2000
bad 9000
...
```

Now I am reading this file line by line and storing it in `HashMap` - First splitted string goes as the key in the HashMap and next splitted string goes as the value in the HashMap and  so I  am able to measure the insertion performance with the below code.

```
Map<String, String> wordTest = new HashMap<String, String>();

try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(FILE_LOCATION);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
        String[] splitString = line.split("\\s+");
        // now put it in HashMap as key value  pair
        wordTest.put(splitString[0].toLowerCase().trim(), splitString[1].trim());

        line = reader.readLine();
    }
}
```

Now how would I implement `Trie` data structure to load the same thing in Trie as I  did for HashMap? And then do a lookup basis on String as well? This is my first time with Trie data structure so little bit confuse.

**Update:-**

Below is my `TrieImpl` class

```
public class TrieImpl {

    //root node
    private TrieNode r;

    public TrieImpl() {
        r = new TrieNode();
    }

    public boolean has(String word) {
        return r.has(word);
    }

    public void insert(String word){
        r.insert(word);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return r.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TrieImpl t = new TrieImpl();

        System.out.println("Testing some strings");
        t.insert("HELLO"); // how do I pass string and its count
        t.insert("WORLD"); // how do I pass string and its count

    }
}
```

And below is my `TrieNode class` -

```
public class TrieNode {

    // make child nodes
    private TrieNode[] c;
    // flag for end of word
    private boolean flag = false;

    public TrieNode() {
        c = new TrieNode[26]; // 1 for each letter in alphabet
    }

    protected void insert(String word) {
        int val = word.charAt(0) - 64;

        // if the value of the child node at val is null, make a new node
        // there to represent the letter
        if (c[val] == null) {
            c[val] = new TrieNode();
        }

        // if word length > 1, then word is not finished being added.
        // otherwise, set the flag to true so we know a word ends there.
        if (word.length() > 1) {
            c[val].insert(word.substring(1));
        } else {
            c[val].flag = true;
        }
    }

    public boolean has(String word) {
        int val = word.charAt(0) - 64;
        if (c[val] != null && word.length() > 1) {
            c[val].has(word.substring(1));
        } else if (c[val].flag == true && word.length() == 1) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Now how would I extend this to passs a particular string and its count and then do a lookup basis on String?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement a Trie data structure?

Comment: Yeah kind of, meaning how to implement `Trie` data structure for my current set of problem which is word frequency  list. As the way I am doing for HashMap, I need to do same thing using Trie.

Comment: You can start by building upon what is asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225540/trie-implementation
. You can also find another implementation here: https://code.google.com/p/trie/source/browse/trunk/trie/src/net/bcharris/trie/TrieImpl.java

Comment: Thanks. How would I use these to pass String words and its count into the  Trie. That's the confusion I am having. Any idea?

Comment: Instead of inserting a single `String` instance into the Trie, you can insert a pair of a string and an int together and modify the code to only act on the string. That way, when you look up an entry, you get the string and it's associated integer in the pair.

Comment: @wiz3kid: I have updated my question with the code but still confuse how  do I extend this? If you can provide an example then this will help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: I have posted an answer with some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a element `frequency` to your `TrieNode` class.

```
public class TrieNode {

    // make child nodes
    private TrieNode[] c;
    // flag for end of word
    private boolean flag = false;
    //stores frequency if flag is set
    private int frequency;
```

Now in the insert method, add the frequency while setting the flag..change method signature appropriately

```
protected void insert(String word, int frequency) {
    int val = word.charAt(0) - 64;
    ..........
    ..........
    // if the value of the child node at val is null, make a new nod
    if (word.length() > 1) {
        c[val].insert(word.substring(1),frequency);
    } else {
        c[val].flag = true;
        c[val].frequency = frequency;
    }
}
```

Now create a new method to get the frequency.It can be done similar to `has` method, where you follow the branches till the end and finally when you find that the flag is set, return the frequency.

```
public int getFreq(String word) {
    int val = word.charAt(0) - 64;
    if (word.length() > 1) {
        return c[val].getFreq(word.substring(1));
    } else if (c[val].flag == true && word.length() == 1) {
        return c[val].frequency;
    } else
        return -1;
}
```

-------------------------------EDIT------------------------

Use `has` method first to check for the string, then use `getFreq` method

```
    public int getFreq(String word) {
        if(has(word))
            return getFreqHelper(word);
        else
            return -1; //this indicates word is not present
    }

    private int getFreqHelper(String word) {
        int val = word.charAt(0) - 64;
        if (word.length() > 1) {
            return c[val].getFreq(word.substring(1));
        } else if (c[val].flag == true && word.length() == 1) {
            return c[val].frequency;
        } else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Somehow insert method is not working. I tried inserting two records as I have in the question but  don't see those two records getting inserted? :(

Comment: Any suggestions? I am finding it little bit difficult on TRIE data structure so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I added two records as per you code. Then if i use `getFreq`, it correctly shows the result

Comment: Yes it works. It was the silly mistake on my end. One thing I have noticed is with your getFreq function - If I try to search for string which is not there in trie, it throws an exception with Array Index  out of range. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Maybe use `has` function to check if string is present, then call the `getFreq` method

Comment: Somehow my has method which I have in the above question always returns false  for the string which is already there in the TRIE. Can you provide an example on this as well if  possible  to make myself clear? Thanks.

Comment: Any thoughts why my has method in the question is not working fine?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint:
Define a class `FrequencyString` like so:

```
class FrequencyString {
    private String string;
    private int frequency;

    public FrequencyString(String str, int freq) {
        this.string = str;
        this.frequency = freq;
    }

    public getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }
}
```

Now modify your Trie implementation methods to accept this new `FrequencyString`. These will be your new signatures:

`TrieImpl`:

```
boolean has(String word);
void insert(String word, int freq);
```

`TrieNode`:

```
boolean has(String word);
void insert(FrequencyString word);
```

If you want to find the frequency for a given word if it exists, change the `has` methods' signatures to this:

```
Integer find(String word);
```

When implementing `find`, return `null` if the word does not exist, or `new Integer(result.getFrequency());` (where `result` is the found `FrequencyString`) if it does.