# Radix(Trie) Tree implementation for Cutomer search in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, trie, radix

I am working on a project and need to search in data of millions of customers. I want to implement radix(trie) search algorithm. I have read and implement radix for a simple string collections. But Here I have a collection of customers and want to search it by name or by mobile number.

**Customer Class:**

```
public class Customer {

    String name;
    String mobileNumer;


    public Customer (String name, String phoneNumer) {
        this.name = name;
        this.mobileNumer = phoneNumer;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPhoneNumer() {
        return mobileNumer;
    }
    public void setPhoneNumer(String phoneNumer) {
        this.mobileNumer = phoneNumer;
    }



}
```

**RadixNode Class:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class RadixNode {
    private final Map<Character, RadixNode> child = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<Customer, RadixNode> mobileNum = new HashMap<>();
    private boolean endOfWord;

    Map<Character, RadixNode> getChild() {
        return child;
    }

    Map<Customer, RadixNode> getChildPhoneDir() {
        return mobileNum;
    }

    boolean isEndOfWord() {
        return endOfWord;
    }

    void setEndOfWord(boolean endOfWord) {
        this.endOfWord = endOfWord;
    }
}
```

**Radix Class:**

```
class Radix {
    private RadixNode root;

    Radix() {
        root = new RadixNode();
    }

    void insert(String word) {
        RadixNode current = root;

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            current = current.getChild().computeIfAbsent(word.charAt(i), c -> new RadixNode());
        }
        current.setEndOfWord(true);
    }

    void insert(Customer word) {
        RadixNode current = root;
        System.out.println("==========================================");
        System.out.println(word.mobileNumer.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < word.mobileNumer.length(); i++) {
            current = current.getChildPhoneDir().computeIfAbsent(word.mobileNumer.charAt(i), c -> new RadixNode());
            System.out.println(current);
        }
        current.setEndOfWord(true);
    }

    boolean delete(String word) {
        return delete(root, word, 0);
    }

    boolean containsNode(String word) {
        RadixNode current = root;

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char ch = word.charAt(i);
            RadixNode node = current.getChild().get(ch);
            if (node == null) {
                return false;
            }
            current = node;
        }
        return current.isEndOfWord();
    }

    boolean isEmpty() {
        return root == null;
    }

    private boolean delete(RadixNode current, String word, int index) {
        if (index == word.length()) {
            if (!current.isEndOfWord()) {
                return false;
            }
            current.setEndOfWord(false);
            return current.getChild().isEmpty();
        }
        char ch = word.charAt(index);
        RadixNode node = current.getChild().get(ch);
        if (node == null) {
            return false;
        }
        boolean shouldDeleteCurrentNode = delete(node, word, index + 1) && !node.isEndOfWord();

        if (shouldDeleteCurrentNode) {
            current.getChild().remove(ch);
            return current.getChild().isEmpty();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void displayContactsUtil(RadixNode curNode, String prefix) 
    { 

        // Check if the string 'prefix' ends at this Node 
        // If yes then display the string found so far 
        if (curNode.isEndOfWord()) 
            System.out.println(prefix); 

        // Find all the adjacent Nodes to the current 
        // Node and then call the function recursively 
        // This is similar to performing DFS on a graph 
        for (char i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++) 
        { 
            RadixNode nextNode = curNode.getChild().get(i); 
            if (nextNode != null) 
            { 
                    displayContactsUtil(nextNode, prefix + i); 
            } 
        } 
    }


    public boolean displayContacts(String str) 
    { 
        RadixNode prevNode = root; 

        // 'flag' denotes whether the string entered 
        // so far is present in the Contact List 

        String prefix = ""; 
        int len = str.length(); 

        // Display the contact List for string formed 
        // after entering every character 
        int i; 
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        { 
            // 'str' stores the string entered so far 
            prefix += str.charAt(i); 

            // Get the last character entered 
            char lastChar = prefix.charAt(i); 

            // Find the Node corresponding to the last 
            // character of 'str' which is pointed by 
            // prevNode of the Trie 
            RadixNode curNode = prevNode.getChild().get(lastChar); 

            // If nothing found, then break the loop as 
            // no more prefixes are going to be present. 
            if (curNode == null) 
            { 
                System.out.println("No Results Found for \"" + prefix + "\""); 
                i++; 
                break; 
            } 

            // If present in trie then display all 
            // the contacts with given prefix. 
            System.out.println("Suggestions based on \"" + prefix + "\" are"); 
            displayContactsUtil(curNode, prefix); 

            // Change prevNode for next prefix 
            prevNode = curNode; 
        } 

        for ( ; i < len; i++) 
        { 
            prefix += str.charAt(i); 
            System.out.println("No Results Found for \""  + prefix + "\""); 
        }

        return true;
    }


    public void displayContactsUtil(RadixNode curNode, String prefix, boolean isPhoneNumber) 
    { 

        // Check if the string 'prefix' ends at this Node 
        // If yes then display the string found so far 
        if (curNode.isEndOfWord()) 
            System.out.println(prefix); 

        // Find all the adjacent Nodes to the current 
        // Node and then call the function recursively 
        // This is similar to performing DFS on a graph 
        for (char i = '0'; i <= '9'; i++) 
        { 
            RadixNode nextNode = curNode.getChildPhoneDir().get(i); 
            if (nextNode != null) 
            { 
                    displayContactsUtil(nextNode, prefix + i); 
            } 
        } 
    }

    public boolean displayContacts(String str, boolean isPhoneNumber) 
    { 
        RadixNode prevNode = root; 

        // 'flag' denotes whether the string entered 
        // so far is present in the Contact List 

        String prefix = ""; 
        int len = str.length(); 

        // Display the contact List for string formed 
        // after entering every character 
        int i; 
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        { 
            // 'str' stores the string entered so far 
            prefix += str.charAt(i); 

            // Get the last character entered 
            char lastChar = prefix.charAt(i); 

            // Find the Node corresponding to the last 
            // character of 'str' which is pointed by 
            // prevNode of the Trie 
            RadixNode curNode = prevNode.getChildPhoneDir().get(lastChar); 

            // If nothing found, then break the loop as 
            // no more prefixes are going to be present. 
            if (curNode == null) 
            { 
                System.out.println("No Results Found for \"" + prefix + "\""); 
                i++; 
                break; 
            } 

            // If present in trie then display all 
            // the contacts with given prefix. 
            System.out.println("Suggestions based on \"" + prefix + "\" are"); 
            displayContactsUtil(curNode, prefix, isPhoneNumber); 

            // Change prevNode for next prefix 
            prevNode = curNode; 
        } 

        for ( ; i < len; i++) 
        { 
            prefix += str.charAt(i); 
            System.out.println("No Results Found for \""  + prefix + "\""); 
        }

        return true;
    } 


}
```

I have tried to search in a collection but got stuck. Any help / suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to search with 2 different criteria (name or phone number), then you will have to keep 2 tries in memory, one for each search criteria. Does this answer your question ?

Comment: @m.raynal thanks for your comments. I have a list of customer objects which have around 18 columns/fields of different primitive types. I want to search customer based on customer name or phone number. How could I maintain this list using trie search? That's I bit working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you 2 ways of doing it.

**First way: with a single trie.**
It is possible to store all you need in a single trie. Your customer class is fine, and here is a possible `RadixNode` implementation.
I consider that there cannot be two customers with the same name, or with the same phone number. If it is not the case (possibility to have people with same name and different phone nb for instance) tell me in a comment I'll edit.
The thing that is important to understand, is that if you want to have two different ways of finding a customer, and you use a single trie, each customer will appear twice in your trie. Once at the end of the path corresponding to its name, and once after the end of the path corresponding to its phone number.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class RadixNode {
    private Map<Character, RadixNode> children;
    private Customer customer;

    public RadixNode(){
        this.children = new Map<Character, RadixNode>();
        this.Customer = NULL;
    }
    Map<Character, RadixNode> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
    boolean hasCustomer() {
        return this.customer != NULL;
    }
    Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }
    void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is only one map storing the node's children. That is because we can see a phone number as a string of digits, so this trie will store all the customers ... twice. Once per name, once per phone number.
Now let's see an insert function. Your trie will need a root,n let's call it `root`.

```java
public void insert(RadixNode root, Customer customer){
    insert_with_name(root, customer, 0);
    insert_with_phone_nb(root, customer, 0);
}

public void insert_with_name(RadixNode node, Customer customer, int idx){
    if (idx == customer.getName().length()){
        node.setCustomer(customer);
    } else {
        Character current_char = customer.getName().chatAt(idx);
        if (! node.getChlidren().containsKey(current_char){
            RadixNode new_child = new RadixNode();
            node.getChildren().put(current_char, new_child);
        }
        insert_with_name(node.getChildren().get(current_char), customer, idx+1);
    }
}
```

The `insert_with_phone_nb()` method is similar. This will work as long as people has unique names, unique phone numbers, and that someone's name cannot be someone's phone number.
As you can see, the method is recursive. I advice you to build your trie structure (and generally, everything based on tree structures) recursively, as it makes for simpler, and generallay cleaner code.
The search function is almost a copy-paste of the insert function:

```java
public void search_by_name(RadixNode node, String name, int idx){
    // returns NULL if there is no user going by that name
    if (idx == name.length()){
        return node.getCustomer();
    } else {
        Character current_char =  name.chatAt(idx);
        if (! node.getChlidren().containsKey(current_char){
            return NULL;
        } else {
            return search_by_name(node.getChildren().get(current_char), name, idx+1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Second way: with 2 tries**
The principle is the same, all you have to do is reuse the code above, but keep two distinct `root` nodes, each of them will build a trie (one for names, one for phone numbers).
The only difference will be the `insert` function (as it will call `insert_with_name` and `insert_with_phone_nb` with 2 different roots), and the search function which will have to search in the right trie as well.

```java
public void insert(RadixNode root_name_trie, RadixNode root_phone_trie, Customer customer){
    insert_with_name(root_name_trie, customer, 0);
    insert_with_phone_nb(root_phone_trie, customer, 0);
}
```

**Edit**: After comment precising there might be customers with the same name, here is an alternative implementation, to allow a `RadixNode` to contain references toward several `Customer`.
Replace the `Customer customer` attribute in `RadixNode` by, for example, a `Vector<Customer>`. The methods will have to be modified accordingly of course, and a search by name will then return to you a vector of customers (possibly empty), since this search can then lead to several results.
In your case, I'd go for a single trie, containing vectors of customers. So you can have both a search by name and phone (cast the number as a `String`), and a single data structure to maintain.

Comment: @mraynal thanks for the reply with solution. Customer name could be same for multiple i.e. multiple customers could be of same name. But phone numbers always unique.