# Which data structure is used to implement a trie?

Tags: java, data-structures, trie

Which data structures should I use to implement a trie in Java?

Do I use a linked list, array, map?

Comment: "*Which data structure is used to implement a Trie ?*" - What is a "*Trie"*?

Comment: @Turing85 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: For example like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225540/trie-implementation (not suggesting that this is a very good reference implementation, it has some obvious problems that the author is asking about, but still...)

Comment: The data structures you mention aren’t on the same level of abstraction, so they aren’t mutually exclusive (for instance, a map can be (and very often is) implemented in terms of an array). In fact, the requirements for the data structure underlying a trie posits some kind of lookup. But how that’s implemented isn’t fixed, and different possibilities have different pros and cons.

Comment: There seem to be numerous examples out in the wild.  I'd suggest Googling "java trie implementation".  There is no one right answer as to how to implement such a structure.

Comment: A trie *is* a data structure. Java does not have a built-in implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The way I implemented a Trie was to use a custom class for the node and store outgoing links as either a HashMap or ArrayList (depending on the number of child nodes).

The reason to split the two cases was that many of the nodes would have just a few child nodes and using a Map would actually slow things down. If I recall correctly I put the limit at about 4 child nodes.